# Array in MySQL Where clause

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array $ziparray that I am trying to use in a MySQL query to check against a database column named 'zip'.  The following code seems logical to me, but I am getting an error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string in...

```
$ziparrayimplode = implode(",", $ziparray);
$listinghistoryquery = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE zip IN ($ziparrayimplode) ORDER BY list_ts DESC";
$listinghistory = mysql_query($listinghistoryquery) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
```

I am absolutely certain the $ziparray is an array.  Can anyone tell me how to make this query work?  Here is the code used to create the array..

```
$countyzipquery = mysql_query("SELECT city_zip FROM dev_cities WHERE city_state='$state' AND city_county='$county' AND city_name='$city'");
$ziparray = array();
while (($ziparrayrow = mysql_fetch_object($countyzipquery)) !== FALSE) {
  $ziparray[] = $ziparrayrow;
```

Here is the output of var_dump($ziparray)

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["city_zip"]=> string(5) "63028" } }
```

Comment: Looks like your $ziparray is a standard object and not an array. Could you throw the code that you use to generate it? (Anonymize it if needed)

Comment: `$ziparray` might be an array, but it seems to contain at least one `stdClass` object, which fails to convert to a string for the `implode` operation itself. Please include the output of `var_dump($ziparray)` in your question.

Comment: Well there you go, you're fetching objects (`mysql_fetch_object`) into `$ziparray` and then you're trying to concatenate those objects.

Comment: Ok, I edited my post above with the info necessary.  How can I fix this?  This is a little over my head apparently.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (($ziparrayrow = mysql_fetch_object($countyzipquery)) !== FALSE) {
```

You're fetching *objects* from your database and then storing those full objects into your `$ziparray` array. You cannot concatenate `stdClass` objects, because they cannot be converted to string (an object needs to define a `__toString` method for that, and `stdClass` instances do not have such a method).

You most likely want to fetch arrays (`mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_object`) and then store only the first element (`$ziparrayrow[0]`) in your `$ziparray`. Alternatively, you can keep the `mysql_fetch_object`, but change your accumulation of elements in `$ziparray`:

```
$ziparray[] = $ziparrayrow->city_zip;
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That's why I love this site.  I always spend a couple of hours trying to figure it out on my own, but when I can't I come here and get a good lesson.  Not only did that fix it, I now understand what I did wrong and learned a little about fetching arrays.